# Using array index value of two different arrays in a for- loop condition?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, data-structures

```
int[] starTime = {0,2,5,8}
int[] relinqtime = {2,4,9,10}

int[] resReqRAM= {9,8,7,5}
int[] totalDuration = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

 for ( int j = 0; j<starTime.length ; j++){
            for( int k =  starTime[j];  k <= relinqtime[j]; k++){
                 totalDuration[k]+= resReqRAM[j];
```

The output i want after executing this loop is that values of `startime[j]` to values of `relinqtime[j]` should become the index of `totalDuration[k]` and for those particular indexes, the values should the value of `resReqRAM[j]` and should add at each iteration.

Like:

```
**iteration 1**

int[] totalDuration = {9,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

**iteration 2**

int[] totalDuration = {9,9,9+8,0+8,0+8,0,0,0,0,0}

**iteration 3**


int[] totalDuration = {9,9,9+8,0+8,0+8,0+7,0+7,0+7,0+7,0}

**iteration 4**

int[] totalDuration = {9,9,9+8,0+8,0+8,0+7,0+7,0+7+5,0+7+5,0+5}
```

I am using the mentioned for-loop for obtaining the same but its giving error:array index out of bound.

Is is like the loop condition should be changed or the logic is wrong?

Comment: Java indexes are 0-based. If an has 10 elements, its index range is from 0 to 9.

Comment: *"should become the index of totalDuration[k]"* -- do you really mean *the index* (so `k`) or rather the value?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer value of startime[j] should become k i.e index of  totalDuration  and value of k should be value of resReqRAM[j]

Comment: @PM77-1 is this the solution?

Comment: @Sjs, okay. so the code tells the truth. ;-) Your description is a little confusing. Yes, as @PM77 and @Rohit already posted, the problem is the `10` in `int[] relinqtime = {2,4,9,10}` it should either be `9` (for the tenth element) or your `totalDuration` needs an eleventh one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The totalDuration array you have initialized has size 10 only.

but in the last iteration you are trying to access the 11Th elements using 
totalDuration[k] where k=10 . So its giving arrayIndexOutOfBound Exception . Since array index starts from 0 . So either you need to increase the size of the array or change the inner loop condition.

Comment: Try this -  int[] starTime = {0,2,5,8} ;
        int[] relinqtime = {2,4,9,10};

        int[] resReqRAM= {9,8,7,5};
        int[] totalDuration = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

         for ( int j = 0; j<starTime.length ; j++){
                    for( int k =  starTime[j];  k <= relinqtime[j]; k++){
                         totalDuration[k]+= resReqRAM[j];
                    }
         }

Comment: Thanks rohit . It worked and I also tried the other way as well by changing the int[] relinqtime  to int[] relinqtime = {2,4,9,9} and keeping the  totalDuration same.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify *starTime* and *relinqtime* value if you need expected result,

```
 int[] starTime = {0,2,5,7} 
 int[] relinqtime = {2,4,8,9}
```

Or, simple add one more zero to *totalDuration* array, which may result one extra value(not recommended).